# JPanel subclass "jumps around" when dragged

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, drag, mousemotionlistener

I'm currently coding on a small "Paint"-program of mine; so far, you can draw on it with a pen, zoom in up to 100x, and choose a color. Next thing I wanted to add was (or is) the possibility to drag the JPanel subclass, on which the image chosen to edit is drawn, around. Basically, by holding down the right mouse button, you change the location of the JPanel subclass, which is located on a JInternalFrame. I've got a code sample that should be working fine on its own; at least it does for me. To replicate the issue, just launch the `DragPanelTest` class and drag your mouse while over the component with the red border - the panel isn't dragged smoothly, but instead jumps back and forth all the time.

code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class DragPanelTest extends JPanel implements MouseMotionListener, MouseListener {
    Point oldDragPt;
    boolean dragEnabled;
    int newX;
    int newY;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Launching Test.java ...");

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Title");
        JInternalFrame intFrame = new JInternalFrame("title", true, true, true, true);
        JDesktopPane deskPane = new JDesktopPane();
        DragPanelTest dragPanel = new DragPanelTest();

        frame.setSize(300, 300);;
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        Dimension d = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        int x = (d.width - frame.getWidth()) / 2;
        int y = (d.height - frame.getHeight()) / 2;
        frame.setLocation(x, y);

        deskPane.setBounds(50, 50, 200, 200);
        deskPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        frame.add(deskPane);


        deskPane.add(intFrame);
        intFrame.setSize(150, 150);
        intFrame.add(dragPanel);
        intFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public DragPanelTest() {
        this.setSize(100,100);
        this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));
        this.addMouseListener(this);
        this.addMouseMotionListener(this);
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        if (e.isMetaDown()) {
            dragEnabled = true;
            oldDragPt = new Point((int) this.getMousePosition().getX(), (int) this.getMousePosition().getY());
        }
        repaint();
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        dragEnabled = false;
        oldDragPt = null;
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        if (e.isMetaDown() && this.getMousePosition() != null) {
            if (oldDragPt != null) {
                if (dragEnabled) {
                    int mouseX = (int) this.getMousePosition().getX();
                    int mouseY = (int) this.getMousePosition().getY();
                    int x = this.getX();
                    int y = this.getY();
                    int diffX = (mouseX - (int) oldDragPt.getX());
                    int diffY = (mouseY - (int) oldDragPt.getY());
                    newX = getX() + diffX;
                    newY = getY() + diffY;
                    this.setLocation(newX, newY);
                    this.repaint();
                    oldDragPt = new Point(mouseX, mouseY);
                }
            } else {
                oldDragPt = new Point((int) this.getMousePosition().getX(), (int) this.getMousePosition().getY());
            }
        }
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {} 
}
```

Note that I left out some `System.out.println()` or `@Override` commands to shorten the code a bit.

Anyhow, if anyone knows what I'm doing wrong / what to improve, I'd be very thankful!

Comment: The reason it's jumping around is because of `getMousePosition`. That's relative to the current component but, since that component is moving, it's affecting where your code thinks the mouse was the last time.

Answer (score 5):

> the panel isn't dragged smoothly, but instead jumps back and forth all the time.

When you have jumping its because the relative movements between the mouse and the component and the parent panel is off. Your code is too complicated to point out the exact line causing the problem.

The basic code for dragging a component around a panel is:

```
public class DragListener extends MouseInputAdapter
{
    Point location;
    MouseEvent pressed;

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me)
    {
        pressed = me;
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me)
    {
        Component component = me.getComponent();
        location = component.getLocation(location);
        int x = location.x - pressed.getX() + me.getX();
        int y = location.y - pressed.getY() + me.getY();
        component.setLocation(x, y);
     }
}
```

For more advanced code with more feature you can also check out the `Component Mover` class found in [Moving Windows](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/14/moving-windows/).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with moving the viewport for a scrollpane.  I think that the when a component is re-positioned, the value of the saved point is relative to the original location and is incorrect relative to the new location.  My solution, which seems illogical to me, made the drag operation flow smoothly.  What I did is to add the point delta back into the saved location.

This is the basic code to drag the viewport:

```
Point priorPanPoint;

public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    Point newPt = subtractPoints(priorPanPoint, e.getPoint());
    priorPanPoint = addPoints(e.getPoint(), newPt);
    newPt = addPoints(getVisibleRect().getLocation(), newPt);
    viewport.setViewPosition(newPt);
}

public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    priorPanPoint = e.getPoint();
}

private Point addPoints(Point p1, Point p2) {
    return  new Point(p1.x + p2.x, p1.y + p2.y); }

private Point subtractPoints(Point p1, Point p2) {
    return new Point(p1.x - p2.x, p1.y - p2.y);
}
```